# Зажатие UI кнопки в Unity

Tags: unity3d, ui

Казалось бы, чего проще, задетектить что зажата UI кнопка в Unity. Либо мне пора ложится спать, либо я совсем не понимаю как сделать что бы была зажата UI кнопка и детектить её через скрипт. Ну проще говоря: Кнопка зажата - происходит что то.

Answer (score 2):

у EventSystem (класс, который отвечает за отлов событий ввода и автоматически добавляющийся при добавлении первого Canvas) есть ряд интерфейсов, которые позволят вам отслеживать любые действия с ним, касающиеся ввода.

Например, в вашем случае нужно два интерфейса IPointerDownHandler и IPointerUpHandler. Унаследуйте от них класс, который висит на кнопке и реализуйте их методы.

PointerDown срабатывает, когда ЛКМ была нажата над объектом, на котором висит скрипт. PointerUp - когда кнопка была отпущена.

Так же, думаю, вам нужно реализовать интерфейс IPointerExitHandler, его метод вызывается, когда курсор покидает объект. Это вам понадобится для, чтобы отключать "зажатие", если игрок выводит курсор за пределы кнопки, при этом не отпуская зажатую кнопку.